# html is but javascript is not rendering in div after onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html, rendering

I'm using a button onclick function to load content into a div called #content on my index page.
Following is the on click javascript function.

```
function myFunction() {

   $('#content').load("content/page1.php");

};
```

It works fine, but when it grabs the loaded php file, all the javascript specifically on that page1.php is not rendered in the #content div.  The html renders fine.  And if you type the absolute path of page1.php in the browser address bar, the page1.php javascript also renders fine.

Any ideas on how to make the javascript render in that #content div?
I'm using a newer version of chrome.

Comment: does the page1.php contains php file from <html>tag

Comment: can you post a bit more code? maybe the .php file

Comment: Can you post the content of the php file? You might need to escape it differently.

Comment: It has the javascript on the page.  And it has html also on the page.

Comment: Here is the page1.php file structure, minus the specifics / functions... I have tried different positions of the script tag but it hasn't helped.  

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<div>
<h1>This section is coming soon!</h1>
<script>-----
;</script>
<h2></h2>
<div id="div2"></div>
</div>

Comment: Also, the page1.php javascript actually renders most of the page1.php div content.  The divs are empty except for styling of a box.  The javascript renders the divs fine on the direct path to the file in the address bar, but when loaded into the index page div by the onclick function, it only renders the box and not the javascript rendered content.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ,

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are **discarded**.

I would suggest you consider restructuring your javascript so that its loaded in a module within the parent page if it makes sense, as it makes things much easier to debug. If that isn't an option, the script blocks are still executed...

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.  I will give that a try!  I didn't think of that.